# Two questions on homogeneous domains

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and let $Aut(G)$ be the group of biholomorphic selfmaps  of $G$. $G$ is called:

(1) homogeneous if $Aut(G)$ acts transitively on $G$, i.e. for any $z,w\in G$ there is $\varphi\in Aut(G)$, such that $\varphi(z)=w$;

(2z) symmetric at $z\in G$ if there is $\varphi\in Aut(G)$, such that $\varphi\circ\varphi =id$ and $z$ is an isolated fixed point of $\varphi$;

(2) symmetric if it is symmetric at any of its points.

It seems that (2) is equivalent to (1) and (2z) for some $z\in G$, but in many cases (1) alone implies (2).

**Q1:** Is there an **elementary** proof, that (2) implies (1)?

Additionally consider the following two properties:

(3z) for any $w\in G$ there there is $\varphi\in Aut(G)$, such that $\varphi(z)=w$ and $\varphi(w)=z$;

(3) for any $z,w\in G$ there there is $\varphi\in Aut(G)$, such that $\varphi(z)=w$ and $\varphi(w)=z$.

Clearly, (3z) for some $z\in G$ implies (1), and then using (1) in addition to (3z), one can show (3).

Also, using the classification of the bounded symmetric domains, one can show that (2) implies (3).

**Q2:** Does the property (3) have a name? Was it considered in the literature? Does (1) imply (3) back, or does (3z) follow from (2z) for some $z\in G$? Is there an **elementary** proof that (2) implies (3)?

Thank you.

Comment: If by "elementary" you allow the introduction of the so called Bergman metric and basic facts of Riemannian geometry then all your questions had elementary answers.

Comment: @Holonomia thank you very much for your attention to my questions! However, it would be much more appreciated, if you posted a bit more elaborated answers. Yes, Bergman metric and its properties are on the edge of elementary for me (especially with references).

Comment: More elaborated answers implies more time and unfortunately I have not much time. Anyway,  for 2) implies 3) take the geodesic $\gamma$ whose with endpoints are $z,w$ and use the symmetry about the middle point of $\gamma$.  Of course you need to show that the symmetry is an isometry and that the geodesic do exist.

Comment: @Holonomia Yes, I thought about this, but I don't understand why that can be done globally, not just in the neighbourhoods, where the exponential mapping is defined.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if we can actually use Bergman metric for **unbounded** domains.